# Configuring nginx + HHVM to run drupal7 and mediawiki get errors

Tags: php, nginx, drupal-7, mediawiki, hhvm

I using nginx + php-fpm to running drupal7 and mediawiki normally.
Since I changed HHVM appeared errors.
drupal7 site after a few seconds get 500 error (nginx error.log don't have relevant information!)
mediawiki site will download the file instead of execute/serve it.
The drupal and mediawiki is latest version (drupal 7.42, mediawiki 1.26.2)
Here is my config files and enabled modules / extensions:

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
# drupal7
server
{
    listen              80;
    server_name         a.xxx.com;
    root     /var/www/html;
    index    index.php index.html index.htm;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;
    set_real_ip_from    127.0.0.1;
    real_ip_header      X-Forwarded-For;

    location  /
    {
        if (!-e $request_filename)
        {
            rewrite  ^/(.*)$   /index.php?q=$1  last;
            break;
        }

        include  hhvm.conf;
    }
}

# mediawiki
server
{
    listen   80;
    server_name   b.xxx.com;
    root   /var/www/html/baike;
    index  index.php index.php5 index.html index.htm;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;
    set_real_ip_from  127.0.0.1;
    real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;

    location /
    {
        rewrite ^/([^?]*)(?:\?(.*))? /index.php5?title=$1&$2 last;
    }

    location /cache
    {
        return 403;
    }

    location /images
    {
        if ($query_string ~ ^\\/:*?\x22<>|%]+("))
        {
            return 403;
        }
    }

    location /includes
    {
        return 403;
    }

        location /languages
    {
        return 403;
    }

    location /maintenance
    {
        return 403;
    }

    location /serialized
    {
        return 403;
    }

    location /tests
    {
        return 403;
    }

    include  hhvm.conf;
}
```

/etc/nginx/hhvm.conf;

```
location ~ \.(hh|php5|php)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME $host;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

- Drupal7 enabled modules:
- acl, addtoany, admin_menu, admin_views, advanced_forum, advanced_forum_more_styles, advanced_help, advanced_help_hint, advpoll, aes, ajax_comments, ajax_register, authcache, autosave, autotag, back_to_top, backup_migrate, barcode, bbcode, beautytips, better_messages, boost, boost_cache_cleaner, boost_captcha, boost_custom_expire_rules, boost_expire, boost_mobile, breadcrumb2, captcha, captcha_after, cdn, chain_menu_access, chart, checklistapi, closedquestion, cmf, cnr, code_snippet, coffee, colorbox, comment_notify, config_pages, content_access, contentanalysis, content_lock, content_menu, contentoptimizer, context, context_http_headers, countdown, counter, csna, ctools, cumulus, diff, download_count, download_file, drupalforfirebug, duoshuo_comment, elements, email, emfield, entity, entitycache, entityreference, entity_translation, expire, fast_404, fasttoggle, featured_content, features, feedback, field_collection, field_permissions, filecache, file_entity, filefield_sources, fivestar, flag, flexiaccess, forum_access, freelinking, geshifilter, get_image, globalredirect, html5_media, httprl, i18n, imagecache_token, image_captcha_refresh, impress, jiathis, jquery_update, l10n_update, langcheck, language_domains, languageicons, libraries, link, linkit, login_history, login_security, logintoboggan, luxe, machine_name, markdown, media, mediafront, media_translation, media_tudou, media_vimeo, media_watermark, media_youku, media_youtube, memcache, menu_token, metatag, microblog, microdata, mobile_switch, modal_forms, module_filter, mollom, mostpopular, multiform, multiupload_filefield_widget, nice_menus, notify, og, page_message, page_title, paging, panels, pasteformat, pathauto, pcp, pdf, persistent_login, piwik, placeholder, plupload, potx, privatemsg, privatemsg_notify_sender, profile2, project, purl, question_answer, quiz, quote, radioactivity, README.txt, redirect, redis, regcode, relevant_content, riddler, rules, rules_link, scheduler, search_api, seo_checklist, services, simple_validation, site_map, smtp, sociallogin, spambot, strongarm, subform, superfish, tablefield, tag, tagadelic, tagclouds, talk, taxonomy_facets, taxonomy_manager, taxonomy_menu, terms_of_use, themekey, title, tmgmt, token, translation_helpers, transliteration, ucuser, ueditor, uiplog, url, username_check, userpoints, userpoints_nc, userpoints_ranking, user_registrationpassword, uuid, variable, varnish, video, views, views_bulk_operations, views_content_cache, views_show_more, views_ticker, visualization, votingapi, webform, wikitools, wordfilter, workbench, workbench_access, workbench_media, workbench_moderation, wysiwyg, xmlsitemap, youtube
- Mediawiki enabled extensions:
- AbuseFilter, AJAXPoll, AjaxShowEditors, AntiBot, AntiSpoof, Auth_UC, Avatar, BlockTitles, CategoryTree, CentralAuth, CentralNotice, Chemistry, ChemPF, Cite, CiteThisPage, CodeEditor, ConfirmEdit, ContentTranslation, Disambiguator, Duoshuo, Echo, EventLogging, FancyBoxThumbs, Flow, FlowThread, Gadgets, GettingStarted, GlobalBlocking, Graph, GuidedTour, ImageMap, InputBox, intersection, Interwiki, JsonConfig, LocalisationUpdate, Lua, MassEditRegex, MassMessage, Math, MathStatFunctions, MobileApp, MobileFrontend, MobileFrontend2, MoegirlRating, MoeUpload, MultiBoilerplate, MultiUpload, MWBlocker, Nuke, PageHistoryAjax, PageImages, PageTools, ParserFunctions, PdfHandler, Piwik, Poem, Popups, PurgeCache, Quiz, README, Renameuser, ReplaceText, SpamBlacklist, SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi, TagContent, TextExtracts, Thanks, ThemeDesigner, TimedMediaHandler, timeline, TitleBlacklist, UniversalLanguageSelector, UsernameBlacklist, Variables, Victoria, VisualEditor, Widgets, WikiEditor, WikiLove, WRLanguageLinks

Sorry for my poor English.
Thanks.